# Java sockets close unexpectedly during many simultaneous connections

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am building a client-server application but whenever I try to connect many sockets to the server, the *client* reports that the socket closed (during the instantiation of the `Socket` object).

The exception I'm getting is: `java.net.SocketException: Socket closed`

The problem always occurs at *exactly* socket number 4077. I set the server's backlog to something like 20,000.

Running OS X El Capitan 64-bit, Java 8.

**The client**

```
public class RunIOClient
{
    private ArrayList<Connection> connections;

    private int connectionCount = 10000;
    private int packetsPerConnection = 0;

    public RunIOClient() throws InterruptedException
    {
        connections = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < connectionCount; i++)
        {
            connections.add(new Connection("localhost", 9000, i + 1));
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        for (int i = 0; i < packetsPerConnection; i++)
        {
            for (Connection c : connections)
            {
                String msg = "Hello " + (i + 1) + " from client " + c.getNumber();
                System.out.println("SENDING: " + msg);
                c.getOut().println(msg);
                Thread.sleep(5);
            }
        }

        Thread.sleep(60000);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        new RunIOClient();
    }
}
```

**And the `Connection` entity**

```
public class Connection
{
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private int number;

    public Connection(String hostname, int port, int number)
    {
        this.number = number;

        try
        {
            socket = new Socket(hostname, port); // exception occurs here
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            System.out.println("Socket " + number + " connected");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Socket getSocket()
    {
        return socket;
    }

    public BufferedReader getIn()
    {
        return in;
    }

    public PrintWriter getOut()
    {
        return out;
    }

    public int getNumber()
    {
        return number;
    }
}
```

**Full stacktrace**

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at Connection.<init>(Connection.java:20)
    at RunIOClient.<init>(RunIOClient.java:16)
    at RunIOClient.main(RunIOClient.java:38)
```

Comment: You probably have exceeded the maximum number of open files. Check if this helps: http://blog.mact.me/2014/10/22/yosemite-upgrade-changes-open-file-limit

Comment: @JanThomä Thanks, but I had that issue at some other point in time, and the exception thrown for that issue is different. I also fixed it at that time.

Comment: Your client does never close any sockets?

Comment: @LittleSanti The full client code is in the post. No sockets are closed.

Comment: @MrGraversen, ok was worth a try though.

Comment: That's suspiciously close to 4096, which is probably the per-process limit of open file descriptors or something. (I suspect per-process limit because it always happens on the same number of open sockets in the process.)

Comment: @MrGraversen No wonder why it stops working, then. You should close each socket as soon as you don't need it.

Comment: @biziclop According to `sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc`, the number is 65k on my system. I upped this limit due to an unrelated error.

Comment: @MrGraversen It must be some other per-process limit then, just look for the number 4096 :)

Comment: @biziclop I'm just not sure where to look

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of this code? If it's intended to exercise a server by creating 10,000 connections, it isn't a valid test for several reasons, starting with the fact that 10,000 outbound connections is generally too many for any client.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it appears that OS X does some funky stuff with file descriptors and their limits.

I moved the project to a Ubuntu 15 machine and the following solved the problem for me:

- Make sure you are root
- In the terminal: `ulimit -n 100000`
- In the terminal: `ulimit -Hn 100000`

This fixes the problem for me. It does, however, only work for the root user (I couldn't change the limit for non-root users).

So, in partial, the problem is resolved.

Answer (score -2):

It is because your server only supports one user, put in a:

```
while(true)
{
   //server accepts clients here
}
```

Create a new thread for each client and pass that connection to your server handler which will have all your server commands.

Comment: The evidence to support this contention is precisely zero.

Comment: Have a look through [this](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/02/13/architecture-of-highly-scalable-nio-server.html).

Comment: Have a look at the question. He gets 4077 connections. Not 1.